# Help me identify this movie man mutates into tree man

Tags: identify-this-movie

This is a movie about a man who creates a potion and then, he drinks it and his body changes/mutates and becomes a man tree or tree man (half tree, half man). And  someone cuts his arm in a fight, and then he puts him (the tree man) in a cell. Then, the prisoner tries to reach the rays of the sun and so, his lost arm grows again (remember that this man was half man and half tree or plant) but unfortunately the other guy drinks the potion too. And then there is an epic fight between the two men. The bad guy uses a sword.

The two mutations are diferent, one man is a kind of man with tree/plant/vegetal escence (his appearance is like silver surfer but in dark green colour and has the vital characteristics of plant/tree/vegetal cell) and the other is like a carnivore (with brown fur).

Comment: Can you recall what year or at least decade the film came out in? What country it's from and/or language it's in?

Answer (score 4):

It's the ***[Swamp Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swamp_Thing_(film))***, the half plant half human (sometimes) superhero from DC Comics. Not to be confused with ***Man-Thing***, the other half plant half human (sometimes) superhero from that other comic company that also had a [tv movie in 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Thing_(film)).

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swamp_Thing_(film)):

> **Swamp Thing** is a 1982 American science fiction film written and directed by Wes Craven, based on the DC Comics character of the same name created by Len Wein and Bernie Wrightson. It tells the story of scientist Alec Holland (Ray Wise) who becomes transformed into the monster Swamp Thing (Dick Durock) through laboratory sabotage orchestrated by the evil Anton Arcane (Louis Jourdan). Later, he helps a woman named Alice (Adrienne Barbeau) and battles the man responsible for it all, the ruthless Arcane.

Arcane being the furry antagonist:

[image]

Said sword:

[image]

And Swamp Thing's Silver Surfer plastic mask look:

[image]

His look evolves throughout the movie. He's much better looking in the sequel:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that blue-eyed blond suits him much better.

Comment: @armfoot that's what happens when you use <strike>Rogaine</strike>  Miracle Gro.